# Связать 2 таблицы с массивом ключей

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Необходимо в MySQL сделать связь 2х таблиц, при этом в одной таблице должно быть несколько ключей к другой таблице. Если сложно объяснил, вот пример:

1 таблица Marks

```
id | mark | models
```

2 таблица Models

```
id | model
```

на выходе нужно получить такой результат:

```
[
{
    "id": 0,
    "mark": "Toyota",
    "models": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "model": "Camry"
                }, ...
              ]
}
]
```

никак не приложу ума, как в таблице Marks полю models добавить массив id второй таблицы

Comment: вам бы названия таблиц местами поменять. ну или структуру. в таблице models должно быть поле mark_id, а не наоборот

Comment: @teran это абстрактные названия, суть в другом: в одном поле указать несколько ключей второй таблицы

Comment: @teran, а если на model могу ссылаться несколько marks?

Comment: вы не правильно мысль строите. несколько моеделй принадлежит одной марке. поэтому в таблицу моделей вписывается столбец, идентифицирующий марку, Поэтому в одном столбец не надо указывать несколько ключей.